# Curly braces in PHP class property that is itself an array

Tags: php, arrays, class, syntax, curly-braces

I've just downloaded an official API OAuth library of a well-known brand from GitHub, and am poking around the code to see how I'm going to call it from our application. The code looks, well, not so great let's say. I've run into this syntax in the code, and to me it looks weird.

There is a class which has the property `$this->_secrets`, which is an array, I can see that in the code. I would expect if you wanted to set the key `consumer_key` you would use the syntax:

```
$this->_secrets['consumer_key']=$APIKey;
```

Instead they have used the following syntax:

```
$this->_secrets{'consumer_key'}=$APIKey;
```

I can't see how this is any different when it comes to how PHP interprets it - I thought use of curly braces was when you wanted to use a variable value as a property name.

Can anyone shed light on why you'd use the second syntax rather than the first?

Comment: It is a perl like syntax adopted by PHP. Both are same. I'll prefer this [] as from a C background. You can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#99015

Comment: you thought it right. *I thought use of curly braces was when you wanted to use a variable value as a property name.*. whether you pass there a string or variable, it will convert it into string value and fetch the data related to it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's just weird that they've used both forms of syntax in the one file, I've never seen use of curly braces without a variable before - very strange.